# How to get out of a code if there is no information filtered to copy instead of it copying everything?

Tags: excel, vba

Ok, it was kind of hard to explain this question but I have an Excel spreadsheet that filters a database I created in Excel for certain values and copies them into their respective sections. I have about 10 different sections and the last two are Adders & Take-Outs which for certain system sizes do not have any items in the database so if I tell it to filter for Adders then it filters and there are no line items in the database so it copies over every item in the database (I don't know why). Below is the code I have for the Adders section.

```
'To add Adders
Range("B12").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Selection.Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ADDERS"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 15).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ADDERS"
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -15).Select
'To filter data
Sheets("Database").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Database").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="4600", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="All"
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Database").Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Adder"
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Database").Range.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array("6201", "6201 Elec", "6201 Eng", "6201 FS Rad", "6201 FS SW", "6201 Rad", "6201 SII", "6201 Train", "CH Elec", "CH Eng", "CH FS", "CH High", "CH SII", "CH Std", "CH SW", "CM", "CM Eng", "Coiler", "Elec", "Elec Eng", "Eng", "ES", "Fluids Eng", "FM", "FS Elec", "FS SII", "FS SW", "Launder", "MA", "MA FS", "MA SII", "MA Train", "ML", "PMDA", "PP High", "PP Low", "QS", "Selee", "Selee Eng", "SII", "STAS", "STAS FS", "Train"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
'To select correct data to copy
Application.Run ("SelectDataToCopy")
'To copy data
Sheets("Quote Sheet").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.Run ("Borders")
Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14)).Select
Application.Run ("Borders")
'To insert formulas
Range("B12").Select
Cells.Find(What:="ADDERS", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Select
Application.Run ("Formulas")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(""ADDERS"",C[-16]:C,17,FALSE)"
Application.Run ("AutofillOptions")
```

See the problem is mainly with the Autofilter section. It filters for all of these criteria but there are no items in the database so it copies everything. Is there a code or any way to alter this code to tell it to step out of this if there are no items filtered. I still want it to create the adders section because I have a button to add custom items I just need it not to copy all the items if there are none filtered. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim NoOfFilteredCells As Long
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Database").Range
    NoOfFilteredCells = .Count - .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
End With
```

This will work if you only need to know if anything is hidden or not. All it is doing is subtracting the amount of visible cells from the total amount of cells, this will tell you how many are hidden.

Then you could use something like

```
If NoOfFilteredCells > 0 Then
    'Put the code that does what you want it to do IF there ARE hidden rows here
Else: Exit Sub
End If
```

Maybe Something Like this:

```
Sub Sample()
Dim NoOfFilteredCells As Long


With Range("B12").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle
    .FormulaR1C1 = "ADDERS"
    .Offset(1, 15).FormulaR1C1 = "ADDERS"
    .Offset(-1, -15).Select
End With
'To filter data
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Database").Range
    .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="4600", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="All"
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Adder"
    .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array("6201", "6201 Elec", "6201 Eng", "6201 FS Rad", "6201 FS SW", "6201 Rad", "6201 SII", "6201 Train", "CH Elec", "CH Eng", "CH FS", "CH High", "CH SII", "CH Std", "CH SW", "CM", "CM Eng", "Coiler", "Elec", "Elec Eng", "Eng", "ES", "Fluids Eng", "FM", "FS Elec", "FS SII", "FS SW", "Launder", "MA", "MA FS", "MA SII", "MA Train", "ML", "PMDA", "PP High", "PP Low", "QS", "Selee", "Selee Eng", "SII", "STAS", "STAS FS", "Train"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    NoOfFilteredCells = .Count - .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
End With

If NoOfFilteredCells > 0 Then
    'To select correct data to copy
    Application.Run ("SelectDataToCopy")
    'To copy data
    Sheets("Quote Sheet").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.Run ("Borders")
    Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14)).Select
    Application.Run ("Borders")
    'To insert formulas
    Range("B12").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="ADDERS", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Select
    Application.Run ("Formulas")
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(""ADDERS"",C[-16]:C,17,FALSE)"
    Application.Run ("AutofillOptions")
Else: Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

But if you need to actually know how many rows have been filtered you can do the same process but divide the number of cells by the number of columns to return the number of rows.

```
Dim lngNoOfFilteredRows As Long
Dim lngNoOfColumns As Long

With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Database").Range
    lngNoOfColumns = .Columns.Count
    lngNoOfFilteredRows = (.Count / lngNoOfColumns - 1) - (.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count / lngNoOfColumns - 1)
End With
```

The minus 1's in the code are to account for headers.